# How to indent string in MVC 5 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.net and MVC 5.

I created a test project using asp.net tutorials.

I am trying to indent text from a table based on another column.

So I have table that looks as below

```
 Title, Level.
 A       1
 B       2
 c       2
 D       3
 E       1
```

Depending on level I want to display above in mvc view as below by adding tabs in front.

```
A
  B
  C
    D
E
```

All what I am getting is

```
A
B
C
D
```

I am not sure how can add tab. Below is my code

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
   <td>
        @Html.Label(item.Title)              
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that goes deep by recursion

```
@helper TreeView(List<Items> items, int level)
{
    foreach (var item in items.Where(i=>i.level == level))
    {
    <li>
        <span>@item.Title</span>
        <ul>
            @TreeView(items, level+1)
        </ul>
    </li>
    }
}
```

Than on the view add

```
<ul>
    @TreeView(Model, 1)
</ul>
```

And set list style to none to remove bullets

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Sorry not sure where to add function. But if I put the above code on top of view, it get few error like name space name "items" could not be found, also item, int, bool dosen't take one argument. But is there not a simple way to add tab to string?? some tike  3 * Tab meaning add three tabs.

Comment: Yes, you need to put in the top of markup.. google how to add helper methods... some details here http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site

Comment: regarding items, you need to put your class, the above class is pseudo code, you need to put you class instead

Comment: Thanks, I will looking into that . Sorry this MVC stuff is so new too me. I am from Delphi world.

Comment: np, ary... wellcome to SO... feel free to ask

Comment: @ary - your issue with "tabs" is not related to MVC, it's HTML.  HTML markup and browsers ignore whitespace like tabs.  You have to use structure, like the suggested embedded unordered lists, or use styling with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answer by ArsenMkrt, you could do it with dynamic padding:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
       <td style="padding-left: @((item.Index-1)*10)px;">
            @Html.Label(item.Title)              
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This will produce something like this

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px;">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 40px;">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px;">E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```